# WebView fails to open local html file with whitespaces in name

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

WebView is unable to show local .htm file because of whitespaces in it's name. I'm getting error

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this   server." UserInfo=0x400ea1900 {NSUnderlyingError=0x400265c80 "The requested URL was not found on this server.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///Users/olgadalton/Library/Caches/ee.64.xxx/_books/Deployment-guide-for-Microsoft-SharePoint-Server-2010_2/OEBPS/Text/Deployment%2520Guide%2520for%2520Microsoft%2520SharePoint%2520Server%25202010_split_000.htm, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///Users/olgadalton/Library/Caches/ee.64.xxx/_books/Deployment-guide-for-Microsoft-SharePoint-Server-2010_2/OEBPS/Text/Deployment%2520Guide%2520for%2520Microsoft%2520SharePoint%2520Server%25202010_split_000.htm, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server.}
```

However file is existing with finder and with terminal listing:

```
ls -l
total 6024
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 olgadalton  staff   3925 Oct 11  2011 Deployment Guide for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010_split_000.htm
```

Permission is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved: there was additional %25 in the url that was needed to be unescaped before using:

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath: .... ]
```

Changed it to:

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath: [ .... stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```